# Dbcontext class simple interpretation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, repository-pattern, dbcontext

would anybody interpret it into simple words as i'm newbie to MVC and can't understand this clearly.

> A `DbContext` instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and
>   Repository patterns such that it can be used to query from a database
>   and group together changes that will then be written back to the store
>   as a unit. `DbContext` is conceptually similar to `ObjectContext`.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Unit of work and Repository are patterns for dealing with data(irrespective of if it is a database or any other storage(may be `List<T>` objects even)) and usually implemented while dealing with data from a database.

It only means that Entity framework internally has these two patterns implemented. To understand it better, just google for Repository Patterns and Unit of work pattern which usually go hand in hand.

If you still do not get the meaning, don't worry - until you know how to work with Entity Framework(Code First is extremely easy to understand, once you understand Linq) the understanding of pattern is not important. Refer back to the same article once you have more experience with the patterns of dealing with data. You only require a little more experience to appreciate them.

Examples of these two patterns are better described by the two interfaces:

```
interface IHomesRepository {
  List<Home> GetAllHomes();
  Home GetHomeById(int id);
  void AddHome(Home home);
  void UpdateHome(int id, Home home);
  void DeleteHome(Home home);
}

interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable{
   IHomesRepository repository {get;}
   // more repositories, if required
   void Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a good example to understand the unit of work and the repository  pattern, i suggest you to read it until the end :
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application